# Spring boot Mongodb Creating a nested document

Tags: spring, mongodb

can any one please tell me what I am missing ? 
I am trying to create a Mongo collection using spring boot mongodb.

I want to create something like this

```
{
    "_id":"123456"
    "entity_name":"some name"
    "entity_desc":"some description"
    "events":[
                {"title":"some title", "description":"some description"},
                {"title":"title2", "description":"description2" }
             ]
}
```

but I am getting this

```
{
   "_id":"123456"
"entity_name":"some name"
"entity_desc":"some description"
"events":[ ]
}
```

my Domain classes are

```
@Document
public class Entity {

     @Id
     private BigInteger id;

     private String name, description;

     private List<Event> events=new ArrayList<Event>();

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

} 




public class Event {

    private String titles;
    private String descriptions;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

}
```

and my repository is

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String>{

}
```

controller is

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository mr;

    /* GET and other methods */


      @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
      public String helloPost(@ModelAttribute Entity entity){



          mr.save(entity);

          return "success";

     }
}
```

and my jsp form is

```
<form:form modelAttribute="entity" role="form">


            <div class="form-group">
             Name <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
        Description <input type="text" id="description"   name="description" /><br />
        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        event <input type="text" id="event" name="event" /><br />
        </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        title <input type="text" id="title" name="title" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
        description <input type="text" id="description" name="description" /><br />
       </div>


        <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>



    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like below?

```
public class Event {

    private String title;
    private String description;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

}
```

**EDIT** : Thanks for the jsp, clearly the way you are passing the values are not picked for child. Spring MVC doesn't support ONGL so it won't pick up child object with dot notation. But there are complex mechanism by setting path. Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854171/spring-mvc-binding-a-list-of-nested-custom-types-to-multiple-jsp-forms) where it did pass child object list through form parameter. So it can be good starting point.

Comment: I tried it too, still result is same , getting an empty array for events , Like I have posted in question

Comment: can you include the JSON you are trying to POST through REST

Comment: I am not using rest, I am returning a jsp.. its a simple experiment with mongodb and spring boot

Comment: your response might be jsp, but your request 'should' be a JSON, or are you using form to post? basically I want to see what Entity argument is passing into your helloPost method. if it's form parameter, I doubt that your child elements of event are being set.

Comment: hmm, Yes I am using form parameter, you are right there must be some issues with my child elements. actually I am new at this, shall i post my jsp form here in edit to my question ?

Comment: Well, yeah that would clarify a few things.